# Is there any precedence for symbols for constructing parse trees?

Tags: parsers, propositional-logic

I am wondering if some symbols such as the ones in propositional logic have precedence over others in drawing parse trees.

For example, the sentence: `p ∧ q → r`, would `∧` take precedence over `→` in becoming the root of the parse tree or vice versa? 

Or is there no precedence meaning, `→` or `∧` could be used the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator precendences have to be specified, either in the grammar or using other means. There is no inherent precendence to rules, but you can fix one arbitrarily.